# How to set the value of a variable by passing the command line parameter at the time of running the script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hive, bigdata

I have a shell script file named **workflow.sh** with the following script:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default -n hiveuser -p Hive@123 --hivevar dbname=$dname -f createCountry.hive
```

where `dname` is a variable and I need to set its value whenever I run the shell script in the command line.

For example when I run ***`./workflow.sh default`***,
it should set the value of the `dname` variable as `"default"`

Answer (score 0):

In bash, ***positional arguments*** are parsed from `$1`, `$2`, .... So you can do it like this:

```sh
dname=$1;
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default -n hiveuser -p Hive@123 --hivevar dbname=$dname -f createCountry.hive
```